# Keeping an object in an absolute position similar to display flex justify and align

Tags: javascript, html, css

I aligned a button with an object of my background image. Sadly the object isn't exactly in the middle of the background image, so I have to use position absolute to position my button.
If the screen size changes, my button moves and does not align with the element of the backgroud anymore.
I want my button to behave as if I used flexbox with justify content and align items center, keeping it in the relativly same position.
Another problem is that my button will become bigger than the screen width on mobile devices messing up the background.
I assume that I have to use javascript to keep track of the display and background size and change the position, as well as changing the button size? Is there a possibility to hide the buttons overflow similar to an images overflow?
I would be very thankfull for ideas/ solutions.

```
<div class="background_container">
      <button type="button" id="button_deploy" class="btn btn-outline-light">DEPLOY</button>
</div>
```

```
.background_container{
    background-color: rgb(15, 15, 15);
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(./media/img/gatetrium_sgp.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    
}

#button_deploy{
    position: absolute;
    top: 30.3vh;
    left: 39.8vw;
    width: 432px;
    height: 432px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: rgba(26, 0, 0, 0.793);
    border-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
        &:hover{
            background-color: rgba(121, 201, 255, 0.186);
            //box-shadow: 0 0 20px 10px rgba(121, 201, 255, 0.186);
        }
}
```

Here are some images to visualize the problem.

[image: how it's supposed to look like]

[image: what happens if the display size changes]

[image: the issue with mobile devices]

Comment: Add `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` but also place the left and top at 50% as well. This should keep the absolutely positioned item in the center regardless of screen size.

Comment: Thank you! I tried the transform: translate cmd but with the vh/vw values. I changed it to 52.1% top and 50.3% left and it works now, really usefull hint!
But: The problem that the button messes up the mobile view, since it's still bigger than the screen is still existent (could make it smaller with @media, but it's not really smooth that way) and the button is too big when the size changes a lot. Do you have a cleaner solution than setting fixed values for the button size with @media?

Comment: Try adding display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; to the button.

Comment: Thank you! Now it works and looks good enough.
Now I have to decide, if I change the size of the button via @media at fixed points or eval the size in relation to the size change via js and inject the values into the css.
You both helped me a lot!